# redux and react connect does not work?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props

I am leaning redux, and I am trying to create a simple test app to see if I can pass props from redux to react component or not but it does not work as I expect. the store it self works fine but it does not pass value to my component can some one please point out the problem with my code? thanks.

```
 const randomNum=()=>{...}
    const ReduxPropsTest =(props)=>(

        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>console.log('but this component does not have the props',props.array)}>test</button>
    </div>
)

const mapStateToProps=state=>{
    {array:state.reducer}
}
connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxPropsTest)

//actions
const addItem=(array=[])=>(
    {
        type:'ADD_ITEM',
        array,
    }
)

//reducer
const reducer=(state=[],action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_ITEM':
        return [
            ...state,
            action.array
        ]

        default:
        return state;
    }
}

//store
const store=createStore(reducer) 

//create test state
store.subscribe(()=>{
    const state=store.getState();
    console.log('I dispatched successfully: ',state)
})
const Jsx=()=>(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ReduxPropsTest/>
    </Provider>
)
store.dispatch(addItem({array:randomNum()}))
store.dispatch(addItem({array:randomNum()}))
store.dispatch(addItem({array:randomNum()}))
store.dispatch(addItem({array:randomNum()}))

ReactDom.render(<Jsx/>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

this is the picture of my problem
[image]

I tried to correct my code based on some suggestions and I none are working so far

```
const randomNum=()=>{...}

const ReduxPropsTest =(props)=>(

    <div>
        <button onClick={()=>console.log('but this component does not have the props',props.array)}>test</button>
    </div>
)

const mapStateToProps=state=>({
    array:state.reducer
})
const Connected = connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxPropsTest)

const addItem=(array=[])=>(
    {
        type:'ADD_ITEM',
        array,
    }
)

const reducer=(state=[],action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_ITEM':
        return [
            ...state,
            action.array
        ]

        default:
        return state;
    }
}

const store=createStore(reducer) 
store.subscribe(()=>{
    const state=store.getState();
    console.log('I dispatched successfully: ',state)
})
const Jsx=()=>(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Connected/>
    </Provider>
)
store.dispatch(addItem({array:randomNum()}))
store.dispatch(addItem({array:randomNum()}))
store.dispatch(addItem({array:randomNum()}))
store.dispatch(addItem({array:randomNum()}))

ReactDom.render(<Jsx/>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

this is the picture of error
[image]

Comment: @ Shubham Khatri This question is not a duplication of the one you point me to. I do not need export method to make my code work and that is not what I ask. I have different problem and different answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`connect` is returning a new component which this the one you need to use.
this line:

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxPropsTest)
```

Will not do anything, as you are not using the new component returned from `connect`.

```
const Connected = connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxPropsTest);
```

Now pass the new component:

```
const Jsx=()=>(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Connected/>
    </Provider>
)
```

another thing, you are not returning an object inside `mapstateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps=state=>({
    array:state.reducer
})
```

**Edit**
Another issue here, is that you passing to the state an Array. **not** an object with the key `reducer` like you expect inside `mapstateToProps`.

You can use the [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) method of `redux` to create a single reducer (root reducer) that will expose an object of key value pairs:

```
const comboReducers = combineReducers({
  reducer
});

const store = createStore(comboReducers)
```

Then you will have a key of `reducer` inside your `mapStateToProps` that you can play with.

Working example:

```js
const { createStore, combineReducers  } = Redux;
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;


const randomNum = () => { return Math.random() };

const ReduxPropsTest = (props) => (

  <div>
    <button onClick={() => console.log('but this component does have the props', props.array)}>test</button>
  </div>
)

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 array: state.reducer
})
const Connected = connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxPropsTest)

const addItem = (array = []) => (
  {
    type: 'ADD_ITEM',
    array,
  }
)

const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
      return [
        ...state,
        action.array
      ]

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const comboReducers = combineReducers({
  reducer
});

const store = createStore(comboReducers)
store.subscribe(() => {
  const state = store.getState();
  console.log('I dispatched successfully: ', state)
})
const Jsx = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Connected />
  </Provider>
)
store.dispatch(addItem({ array: randomNum() }))
store.dispatch(addItem({ array: randomNum() }))
store.dispatch(addItem({ array: randomNum() }))
store.dispatch(addItem({ array: randomNum() }))

ReactDOM.render(<Jsx />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.6/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.7.2/redux.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I tried what you say, and I still got the same problem...):

Comment: I tried props.reducer, I tried props alone none of them worked, and I use porps.array because in mapStateToProps i set the state.reducer to array.

Comment: have you fixed `mapstateToProps`? it wasn't returning the object as i mentioned in the answer

Comment: yes I did, I used ES6 return function like you suggested and I used ES5 normal return like the other comment suggested and I updated the question with the same error

Comment: i've updated my answer, i added another explanation as well as a running and working example with your code. hope that helps clarify the problem and solution.

Comment: wonderful, it works wonderful, thank you verymuch

Comment: You are welcome ☺

Answer (score 0):

Add return in mapstatToprops like

```
const mapStateToProps=state=>{
    return {array:state.reducer}
}
```

Comment: it does not work, I still have the same error

Comment: See the answer given by @user:3148807. I wasabout edit my answer But he has done it before me :)

Comment: can you please direct me to that answer, I tried to search for the user but I can't find him, thanks